# Bulk upload documents and apply metadata from CSV

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, export, import, csv

I have a weekly export in CSV format that contains employee information from another system.

I would like to loop through the CSV and upload X number of documents to a permanent document library on a default template from a template library elsewhere with each new document having a unique name i.e. Employee1, Employee2 that I then need mapped to the corresponding row on the CSV, amount depents on total rows.

I then need to update the metadata of each new document to the corresponding row on the CSV file.

**The script below only works if there is on row on the CSV.**

Thanks to http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/10/bulk-upload-files-to-sharepoint-using-powershell.html

```
#Configuration Variables
$SiteURL="http://sharepointdev/eregister"
$LibraryName="employees"
$FilesPath="\\sharepointdev\DavWWWRoot\Lists\Templates\"
$TemplateName="Employee Agreement"
$CSVFilePath="e:\weeklyexport\employees.csv"

#Get the Web
$Web = Get-SPWeb $SiteURL

#Get the Target Document Library to upload
$Library = $Web.GetFolder($LibraryName)

#Get CSV file contents
$CSVData = Import-CSV -path $CSVFilePath

#Count CSV rows
[int]$LinesInFile = 0
$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $CSVFilePath
 while($reader.ReadLine() -ne $null){ $LinesInFile++ }

    write-host "Number of records to process:"$LinesInFile

#Iterate through each Row in the CSV
Foreach ($Row in $CSVData)
{

    write-host "Uploading File:"$Row.Name

    #Get the File from local disk 
    $SourcePath= Join-Path $FilesPath -ChildPath  $Row.Name
    $SourceFile = (Get-ChildItem $SourcePath).OpenRead()

    #Set Metadata Hashtable For the file
    $Metadata = @{"FullName" = $Row.Full_Name;"Department" = $Row.Department;"Position" = $Row.Position;"StartDate" = $Row.Start_Date}

    #upload the file              
    $uploaded = $Library.Files.Add($Row.Name+$LinesInFile, $SourceFile, $Metadata, $TRUE)
}
```

Can anyone help to further progress this script to handle multiple records?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Can anyone suggest anything please?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I dont actually know why it is not working for you on multiple lines.

I tested following and it iterates as expected:

> $config=import-csv C:\Temp\anything.csv
>
> foreach ($cfgLine in $config) {
>
> ```
>  write-host $cfgLine.test1
>  write-host $cfgLine.test2
>  write-host $cfgLine.test3
> ```
>
> }

Have you got any error messages?

Try to comment out this part of code:

> [int]$LinesInFile = 0
>
> $reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $CSVFilePath
>
> while($reader.ReadLine() -ne $null){ $LinesInFile++ }
>
> write-host "Number of records to process:"$LinesInFile